# Why is this union apparently holding more than one value?

Tags: c++, sdl, unions

I'm new to using unions and confused as to how this test is passing,  `SDL_Event` being a union:

```
TEST(basic_check, test_eq) {
  Dot dot;

  SDL_Event event;            // this is a union, see below
  event.type = SDL_KEYDOWN;   // <= I use one member here

  SDL_Keysym keysym;          // this is a struct
  keysym.sym = SDLK_UP;
  event.key.keysym = keysym;  // <= I use another member here

  dot.handleEvent(event);     // <= but this function accesses value of the first member

  EXPECT_EQ(-Dot::DOT_VEL, dot.getVelY());
}
```

My understanding is that a union can ever only hold one value.

In this test however, I set a value into `event.type`, one member of the union; Then I update `event.key`, another member of the union.  More precisely `event.key` is a struct and I update its member having a struct `SDL_Keysym`.

Here the code of the function that is then called:

```
void Dot::handleEvent(SDL_Event& e) {

  if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && e.key.repeat == 0) { //<== access two alternate members?
    switch (e.key.keysym.sym) {   
      case SDLK_UP: 
        velY -= DOT_VEL;
        break;
      case SDLK_DOWN:
        ...   // followed by a lot of other cases 
    }
  }
}
```

I'm confused, because the `if` condition accesses two members of the union  (see comment above). I thought they would be exclusive.

For information, `SDL_Event` and `SDL_KeyboardEvent` are defined like this:

```
typedef union SDL_Event
{
    Uint32 type;                    /**< Event type, shared with all events */
    SDL_CommonEvent common;         /**< Common event data */
    SDL_WindowEvent window;         /**< Window event data */
    SDL_KeyboardEvent key;          /**< Keyboard event data */
    ...            // and a long list of other events 
    ...
} SDL_Event;


typedef struct SDL_KeyboardEvent
{
    Uint32 type;        /**< ::SDL_KEYDOWN or ::SDL_KEYUP */
    Uint32 timestamp;
    Uint32 windowID;    /**< The window with keyboard focus, if any */
    Uint8 state;        /**< ::SDL_PRESSED or ::SDL_RELEASED */
    Uint8 repeat;       /**< Non-zero if this is a key repeat */
    Uint8 padding2;
    Uint8 padding3;
    SDL_Keysym keysym;  /**< The key that was pressed or released */
} SDL_KeyboardEvent;
```

Comment: Can you say more clearly what it is that is confusing you? What do you expect to happen here, or why do you think it ought not to work?

Comment: What union? Please include relevant code in your question.

Comment: A union is supposed to only hold one value, yet it is holding two.  It holds the correct e.type and the correct e.key.keysym.sym

Comment: I strongly douibt `SDL_Event` is a `union`! See [ask], provide a [mcve] and all required information. So what is you **specific** problem**?

Comment: Possibly `e.type` and `e.key` share common initial sequence. You'll probably find that the first member of `SDL_KeyboardEvent` is a `Uint32`

Comment: @Olaf: I just checked, he's totally right: https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlevent.html and https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlkeyboardevent.html

Comment: A union can only hold one value at one time.  But those values can be structs with multiple values.

Comment: @brianbeuning: That's unrelated to the issue

Comment: @MooingDuck: Not completely. Actually, that `union` is more like a `struct` with type` plus a union-member, see the answer. Without more information, it looks like a bad approach, I'd use a `struct` with the `type`, but then there might be reasons for this. (One reason is to keep the hierarchy flat, but an anonymous struct member will do the same)

Comment: @SeanBollin I think you have not posted the right source code... apparently (from googling anyway), some versions of SDL have `Uint32 type;` and some have `Uint8 type;` , hopefully any particular version is consistent in both cases but you've posted one of one and one of another. Please check the actual source you are compiling

Comment: @M.M: That was actually my bad, I posted the second piece of code from online and didn't verify that it matched the first bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right about unions having at most one member active at any given time.

But the standard makes a guarantee, in order to facilitate the use of the union (and in particular to find out, like here, which is the active element):

> **9.5/1:** (...) If a standard-layout union contains several standard-layout structs
>   that share a common initial sequence, and if an object of this
>   standard-layout union type contains one of the standard-layout
>   structs, it is permitted to inspect the common initial sequence of any
>   of standard-layout struct members;

In your example, the `SDL_Event` union has a union member `Uint32 type` and all the `SDL_XXXEvent` structures start as well with an `Uint32`.  This is the common initial sequence, so that it can be inspected using any of the members (and the simplest one is just `type`).

***Edit: interesting remark (taken over from the comments)***

As you've pointed out, the test is not only inspecting: it also writes in `type` using the `event.type` and then assign the `keysym` in `event.key`.  You therefore wonder if the change of active member (from `type` to `key`)  wouldn't invalidate common initial sequence.

Be assured that this works perfectly. The C++ guarantee on inspection ensures  that after the assignment of `event.type` (common initial sequence),   `event.key.type` is also `SDL_KEYDOWN`. As you then change only `event.key.keysim` there is no reason that `type`'s value changes.

Note however that `timestamp`, `WindowsID` and the other members of `event.key` are in an undefined state. Your test doesn't use them, so there is no reason to fail. But to avoid this kind of potential issues, a better approach could be to construct an `SDL_KeyboardEvent`, initialize it properly and copy the whole struct it into `event.key`

Comment: Actually that is not an exception, there still is only one member "active". It is just that if all members have the identical initial members, it does not matter which member you use to access those members.

Comment: I'm reading from this that it is ok to inspect the "common initial sequence".  To me, that means I can inspect the first uint32 type on each struct.  However, does this answer why the e.key.keysym.sym field is still valid?  That is not of type uint32

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks for the suggestion.  I've added it.

Comment: @Olaf you are of course right. I used the term "exception" as you can access this sequence using any of the members, in opposition to only the active one.  But I've reformulated to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: @SeanBollin Because the value in the common type can be accessed from any members, you have the guarantee that before your assignment, `event.key.type` is `SDL_KEYDOWN`.  As you then change only `event.key.keysim` there is no reason that the type value changes.  Note however that `timestamp`, `WindowsID` and the other members of `event.key` are in an undefined state. But your test doesn't use them, so there is no reason to fail. To avoid this kind of issues,a better approach could be to construct an `SDL_KeyboardEvent`, initialize all its members and copy the whole struct it into `event.key`

Comment: @Christophe: I didn't see necessitiy to correct. What I wanted to point out is that with regard to the identical initial sequence, indeed one could say all members are "active", resp. can be used to access them data. It is fine the standard states that clear. In fact, this allowance is just a result of other parts of the standard (identical layout for identical members, allowance of aliasing through `union`, no padding before first member, all members of a `union` start at offset `0`, etc.). And , of course, because a `union` does not track which member currently is stored.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closer at [`SDL_Event`](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlevent.html) you will see that it's *mostly* a unio of structures, where each structure have the same initial signature (having a single 8-bit unsigned integer as the first member).

**That** is what makes it work. Even if the structures in the union will have different size, all will have the same member `type` as the first member.

That is a simple way to emulate *inheritance*, meaning that all the structures in the `SDL_Event` union to be siblings to each other.

Also, using a union to represent multiple types as a kind of [*type punning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) is explicitly allowed by the C specification.

---

***However...*** Since the question is tagged as a C++ question, this is technically *undefined behavior*.

For backwards compatibility with C most (if not all) C++ compilers will allow this without any complaints.

Comment: This is a C++ question. And type punning is not used here anyway.